# Making a query on ES using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

So i was trying to fetch all documents with duplicate data in field "svctag".

I made the following query for the same.

```
"aggs": { "svctag": { "terms": { "field": "svctag","size": 0, "min_doc_count": 2}}}
```

I also tried running it with this and still got the same error.

```
{"aggs": {"duplicateNames": {"terms": {              "field": "svctag","size": 0,              "min_doc_count": 2}}}}
```

But on running this, I get the following error.

```
Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse query [\"aggs\": { \"svctag\": { \"terms\": { \"field\": \"svctag\",\"size\": 0, \"min_doc_count\": 2}}}]","index":"logstash-data","line":1,"col":430}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"logstash-data","node":"PDjSn1G3SYS7jgGLRBV2HQ","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse query [\"aggs\": { \"svctag\": { \"terms\": { \"field\": \"svctag\",\"size\": 0, \"min_doc_count\": 2}}}]","index":"logstash-data","line":1,"col":430,"caused_by":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Cannot parse '\"aggs\": { \"svctag\": { \"terms\": { \"field\": \"svctag\",\"size\": 0, \"min_doc_count\": 2}}}': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 6.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <EOF> \r\n    <AND> ...\r\n    <OR> ...\r\n    <NOT> ...\r\n    \"+\" ...\r\n    \"-\" ...\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    \"^\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ","caused_by":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 6.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <EOF> \r\n    <AND> ...\r\n    <OR> ...\r\n    <NOT> ...\r\n    \"+\" ...\r\n    \"-\" ...\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    \"^\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    "}}}}]}}
```

Where am i going wrong? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Kibana input field only supports queries and not aggregations. If you want to aggregate your data you can use visualizations instead, which are leveraging aggregations.

In your case, you can:

1. pick a pie chart,
2. then choose "New search",
3. then "Split slices",
4. then pick the "terms" aggregation
5. then pick the `svctag` field and configure size=0

You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seem to work. 
But I have a little doubt. actually i have 2 source files i am taking data from, one has 8 fields and other one has 5 fields. Few of the fields are common. I am storing both under one index. I want to check how many matches are there in field1 of source file1 and field2 of source file two. Would this approach help me then?

Comment: Yes, by using another `terms` sub-aggregation on `field1` and/or `field2`

Comment: Hello. I think I didn't make myself clear. I do no wish to find out how many of each type are there, what I want to do is just know number of matching data points. So i want an overall count. right now i am geting A has 2, B has 2, C has 3, D has 1. But what I am looking for here is there are 3 matches (since there are multiple entries of A B and C)